# "Invalid server response" on submit from PDF in certain situations

Tags: itext7

I created a PDF with a form. For certain default values (so far I have only encountered this problem with certain values in Hebrew and Russian - never with English), if the default value is submitted I receive an immediate Invalid Server Response error. From the server-side log I see that the request never arrived at the server. With other default values (even in Hebrew), or if the same default value is entered manually, the submit succeeds.
Here is the code which sets the default values:

```
    textfield.setValue(JavaItext.reverseString(params.defval));
    textfield.setDefaultValue(new PdfString(JavaItext.reverseString(params.defval)));
```

textfield is a PdfTextFormField object, of course. The method reverseString() reverses the order of the characters in a Hebrew string.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

[Sample PDF](http://asb.aman.co.il:8080/formit/daviddev/new%20example.pdf)

Comment: Pleaser share an example pdf to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sample PDF added.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the submit button action JacaScript command, an invalid encoding name is used.

The JavaScript action in the PDF is:

```
this.submitForm({cURL: "http://asb.aman.co.il:8080/formit/ActiveDocument/FormMonitor", cSubmitAs: "HTML", cCharset: "UTF-8"});
```

According to the JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference, though,

> `cCharset` (optional, Acrobat 6.0) The encoding for the values submitted. String values
>   are `utf-8`, `utf-16`, `Shift-JIS`, `BigFive`, `GBK`, and `UHC`.
>
> If not passed, the current Acrobat behavior applies. For XML-based formats,
>   `utf-8` is used. For other formats, Acrobat tries to find the best host
>   encoding for the values being submitted.

Thus, `"UTF-8"` is not a valid value, so the default behavior kicks in and Adobe Reader determines a "best host encoding". In the case at hand this is some other encoding, in my tests some single-byte encoding.

The server tries now tries to parse the data as UTF-8 encoded data which fails:

> Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 - Error report
>
> ## HTTP Status 500 -
>
> **type** Exception report
>
> **message**
>
> **description** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception**
>
> ```
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>     java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
>     il.co.aman.apps.Utf8.getUnicode(Utf8.java:113)
>     il.co.aman.apps.WebParams._getEntity(WebParams.java:71)
>     il.co.aman.apps.WebParams.getEntityParams(WebParams.java:163)
>     il.co.aman.formit.FormMonitor.doGet(FormMonitor.java:65)
>     il.co.aman.formit.FormMonitor.doPost(FormMonitor.java:370)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:122)
> ```
>
> **note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

Replacing the invalid `"UTF-8"` by the valid `"utf-8"` causes the data to be encoded as desired. The web service, therefore, now can properly decode the data and process it.

---

In addition to fixing the JavaScript in the PDF, you should also harden your service, e.g. by

- making `il.co.aman.apps.Utf8.getUnicode` fail more gracefully (with some tagged exception caught in `il.co.aman.apps.WebParams.getEntityParams` and used there to mark the retrieved parameters as *incomplete due to encoding issues*) and
- improving `il.co.aman.formit.FormMonitor.doGet` to react sensibly in such a situation.

Furthermore, you say

> From the server-side log I see that the request never arrived at the server.

Either you have some proxy in-between which hiccups before the request reaches the server, or Adobe Reader in your Locale determines a different "best host encoding" which causes different failures altogether, or your logging starts logging too late. I would suggest investigating this, too, and improving your logging architecture accordingly if it is to blame.